# How to calculate the supporting force for a cantilever beam?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, statics

How do I find the supporting force $R_A$ and the moment $M_A$?

Should I use the sum of moments or?

Comment: Hello Rails, Welcome to Physics.SE. This is a site which supports conceptual Q&A posts and discussions relating such (as defined in our FAQ). On the darker side, it also discourages posts which specifically ask other users to solve a set of home-made problems. Please have in mind to read [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) before asking such questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a statics problem, so yes, you should enforce that the sum of the forces equals zero, and the sum of the moments equals zero. For a uniformly distributed load, you can treat is as a point load applied at the midpoint of the distribution when calculating the moment at point A.

Comment: Where can i find moments from point A?